# Efficient diagonalization of sparse matrices using GNU Octave

Tags: octave, scientific-computing, eigenvalue

Does GNU Octave have any routine (e.g. [Lanczos Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm)) to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of sparse matrices, which will be more efficient than the default `eig`?

If this is not yet available in Octave, is something similar available in MATLAB or Mathematica?

Comment: matzeri's answer is the answer to your question, but, in case you're interested, the octave sources use the word lanczos in exactly two places, both in lo-specfun.cc. You could have a look at the source and decide if that's what you had in mind. (obviously the method could be used elsewhere without a label)

Answer (score 1):

What about reading the manual:

https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Sparse-Functions.html#Sparse-Functions

https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Sparse-Linear-Algebra.html#index-eigs

Comment: True, and also helpful, but surely you can rephrase that a _tiny_ bit. :)  (plus, link-only answers are generally not considered good answers on SO -- not that I foresee links to octave documentation breaking anytime soon ...)